# Maintaining state of a component in angular

Tags: angular, angular8, syncfusion, asyncfileupload

I have a component which uploads files to blob storage, I have side bar navigation in my app, I need a way so that if I have uploaded some files in my uploading component and went to another component without completing the files progress, when I revisit the uploading component I can still see the progress. I want let the uploading process continue even when the component is not in DOM. Is there a feasible solution for the above scenario, or do I need to create a global component for handling this.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Answer (score 0):

When you switch to another page in the sidebar component, angular routing will happen. The Router destroys a routed component while visiting the previous page. You can store the data like filesData using the angular services. But we cannot maintain the state of the uploader. Kindly refer the below link,

**Reference link:** https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Hi, what I want to achieve is that I have a file uploading at 25% and when I move to another component, the uploading should not stop at all. that way I can show the real time uploading progress when I came back to uploading component